# MySQL UPDATE fieldnames from array with fieldvalues from array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a MySQL query (in PHP) that will update a set of fieldnames contained within an (imploded) array with a set of values contained within another (imploded) array.

What I have right now is this:

```
$edit= mysql_query ("UPDATE tablename SET `".$EXPfields."` = '".$EXPvalues."' 
WHERE ID = '$ID'");
```

But for `$EXPfields = EXP1, ?EXP2?, ?EXP3`  
and `$EXPvalues = Communications', 'Electronics', 'Engineering` 
(both imploded arrays, ? is actually a backtick: `)

I get the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  ' ?EXP2?, ?EXP3? = 'Communications', 'Electronics', 'Engineering' ' at line 2

(again, ? is actually a backtick `)

I've been playing around with this for ages, but I can't see where I have gone wrong, help pls! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that should read:
$EXPfields = EXP1?, ?EXP2?, ?EXP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update queries have the following syntax:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = expression
WHERE predicates;
```

You could loop through the array of fields and create a new array containing both column names and values. For example:

```
$update_sql = '';

for($i = 0;  $i < count($EXPfields);  ++i)
{
    $update_sql = "`" . $EXPfields[$i] . "` = '" . $EXPvalues[$i] . "', ";
}

$update_sql = substr($update_sql, 0, -2);

$edit = mysql_query("
    UPDATE
        tablename
    SET
        " . $update_sql . "
    WHERE
        ID = '$ID'");
```

Comment: Thanks Michiel, but I am still getting the same syntax error.
And palindrom, I don't want to structure it like that, because the arrays of field names/values are very long.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Don't add comments like this as answers.

Comment: If you want to update several fields, you must use the field1 = val1, field2 = val2, etc syntax in SQL.

Comment: OK sorry for the answers instead of comments, I'm new to this website.   @Michiel: writing a loop to create a new array containing fields and values looks promising, but how do I do this?! Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: @RLJ: Have you made any progress yet?

Comment: @Michiel: Thanks, I think for your code to work $EXPfields and $EXPvalues need to be arrays though, not imploded arrays right? So I have added the following: $EXPfieldsarray = explode("?, ?",$EXPfields); (? = backtick ')
    $EXPvaluesarray = explode("', '",$EXPvalues);       But I get the following error message: Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM' in .... on line 115 , where line 115 is where it says: for($i = 0;  $i < count($EXPfieldsarray);  ++i)

Comment: @Michiel, I have edited your code and now it works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
  SET
    field1 = expression1,
    field2 = expression2,
    field3 = expression3
 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do comma separated field=value pairs. eg:

`$query = UPDATE ?tablename? SET ?field1?='value1', ?field2?='value2' WHERE (?field3?='value3')`